# Django: How to list products of a category

Tags: django

Trying to get the children of a one to many relationship using the related_name property.

What I've tried so far doesn't work:

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        related_name='products',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        default=1
    )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from Shop.models import Category

def product_list(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    products = category.products.all()
    context = {
        'customCSS': '/static/css/product_list.min.css',
        'title': category.name,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

product_list.html

```
{% block content %}
    <ul>
    {% for product in products %}
        <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Off topic of the question, but you shouldn't be passing paths to your css via the context. Use `{% static %}` in your templates. Here are the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `products` in `context`. Pass them to template like this.

```
products = category.products.all()
context = {
    'customCSS': '/static/css/product_list.min.css',
    'title': category.name,
    'products': products,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `context` you pass to `render` does not include `products`, so naturally it can't render `products`. Include it and the code should work:

```
context = {
    'customCSS': '/static/css/product_list.min.css',
    'title': category.name,
    'products': products
}
```